# Error in PHP-5.6.13 when compile with OpenSSL 1.0.1p

Tags: php, apache

In our production environment we need to apply SSL certificate on our Apache web server.

For this purpose I need to deploy a self signed certificate on my test server  with same configuration of live server. The machine details are below:

1. Red hat Linux X86_64  6.1
2. Apache server 2.4.16
3. PHP 5.6.13

Installation steps of OpenSSL are mention below:

```
./config --prefix=/u/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/u/usr/local/openssl -fPIC no-gost no-shared no-zlib
make
make install
open SSL 1.0.1p is successfully compiled with Apache server 2.4.16
```

But issue is that, it does not compile with PHP. Error message is mentioned below for your reference:

```
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_pkey_get_details':
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3938: undefined reference to `_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY'
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3938: undefined reference to `KEY_get0_group'
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3941: undefined reference to `GROUP_get_curve_name'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_is_private_key':
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3492: undefined reference to `KEY_get0_private_key'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_pkey_export':
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3750: undefined reference to `_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY'
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3750: undefined reference to `_write_bio_ECPrivateKey'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_pkey_export_to_file':
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3681: undefined reference to `_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY'
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3681: undefined reference to `_write_bio_ECPrivateKey'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_select_crypto_method':
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:965: undefined reference to `TL_2_client_method'
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:965: undefined reference to `TL_2_server_method'
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:957: undefined reference to `TL_1_client_method'
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:957: undefined reference to `TL_1_server_method'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `set_server_ecdh_curve':
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1211: undefined reference to `EEY_new_by_curve_name'
/u1/softwares/php-5.6.13/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1220: undefined reference to `EEY_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

Comment: When compiling openssl, use `shared` instead of `no-shared`.

Comment: compiling openssl with shared same error above mention it